# D3 js map overflowing SVG Canvas - Part of the map is completely hidden

Tags: d3.js, maps

Am terribly irritated in making this simple (very very simple map) to get it work

Here is the JSON

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo-boundaries-world-110m/master/countries.geojson
```

This is the code

```
            var w = 800;
            var h = 800;


            var svg = d3.select("#map")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            //Load in GeoJSON data



            d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo-boundaries-world-110m/master/countries.geojson', function(error,geoJSON){
                    svg.selectAll("path")
                   .data(geoJSON.features)
                   .enter()
                   .append("path")
                   .attr("d", path)
                   .style("fill", "steelblue");
               });
```

And all is see is , one huge Africa map and rest of the map is eaten by SVG width. How to resize the map to fit SVG size.d3

Comment: Could you create a codepen example?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the projection:

I am assuming you need geoEquirectangular projection so your code will become:

```
var projection = d3.geoEquirectangular()
    .scale(h / (2*Math.PI))//scale it down to h / (2*Math.PI)
    .translate([w/2, h/4]);//translate as per your choice

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);
```

Other projection are [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Projections.md)

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/koTpfC7Dev79uyyD2W4Q?p=preview)

Comment: Yeh.. I see this projection every where.. But why there aint a simple function like "Scale"??

Comment: And what is geoEquiRectangle

Comment: I didn't knew about this, this is awesome, thank you!